# Show only sibling div with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a codepen with an example.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNgvwV

When you click the button and it changes to "green" - checked, the sibling "time_container" should show.

```js
$(".button_cell").click(function() {
  var self = this, // Cache
    div1 = $('.check_button', self), // Cache
    div2 = $('.checked_button', self), // Cache
    div3 = $('.red_check', self), // Cache
    divtemp = $('.time_container', self); // Cache

  if (div1.is(':visible')) {
    div1.hide();
    $(div2, divtemp).show();
  } else if (div2.is(':visible')) { // Use else if
    div3.show();
    $(div2, divtemp).hide();
  } else if (div3.is(':visible')) { // Use else if
    div3.hide();
    div1.show(); // Use multiple selectors
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  color: #282828;
  margin: 0;
}
.button_cell {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE10+ */
  margin: 10px;
}
.check_button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: gray;
}
.checked_button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
  background: green;
}
.red_check {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
  background: red;
}
.time_container {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="button_cell">
    <div class="check_button">Empty</div>
    <div class="checked_button">Checked</div>
    <div class="red_check">Red Checked</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time_container">Time Container</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="time_container">This one should not be shown</div>
```

I can't get this to work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are already storing the jQuery objects inside `divtemp` so `$(div2, divtemp)` won't work because div2 ,divtemp are not valid selectors, they are objects.

```js
$(".button_cell").click(function() {
  var self = this, // Cache
    div1 = $('.check_button', self), // Cache
    div2 = $('.checked_button', self), // Cache
    div3 = $('.red_check', self), // Cache
    divtemp = $('.time_container'); // Cache

  if (div1.is(':visible')) {
    div1.hide();
   div2.show();divtemp.show();
  } else if (div2.is(':visible')) { // Use else if
    div3.show();
    $(div2, divtemp).hide();
  } else if (div3.is(':visible')) { // Use else if
    div3.hide();
    div1.show(); // Use multiple selectors
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  color: #282828;
  margin: 0;
}
.button_cell {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE10+ */
  margin: 10px;
}
.check_button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: gray;
}
.checked_button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
  background: green;
}
.red_check {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
  background: red;
}
.time_container {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="button_cell">
    <div class="check_button">Empty</div>
    <div class="checked_button">Checked</div>
    <div class="red_check">Red Checked</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time_container">Time Container</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="time_container">This one should not be shown</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the updated codepen link - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvNeRj)

Also note that the earlier code of yours for referring `$(div2, divtemp).show();` is referring to first object only not the second object 'divtemp'

Comment: Hi and thanks, I can see it works as intended in your snippet, but I can't get it to work on my site. Also, I don't understand what line of codes makes only the sibling container show, and not the other one?

Comment: Ah, I see. you didn't close the button_cell div, so you made the time_container a child?

Comment: The line 'var self = this' defined in code under button click and you are referring the sibling container with this button, due to which it is not affecting other one

Comment: Also try with by removing self in line 'divtemp = $('.time_container', self); ' you will get clear idea

Comment: I tried removing ", self" after time_container, and then it works but it shows all divs with time_container. if I add self back in, then it doesn't work because in my code example, the time_container div is a SIBLING and not a CHILD like in the code example above.